# Solved: What causes Cannot convert the "s.m.a.ThrottlingJob" ... to "m.m.i.CimInstance" when registering a scheduled task with Powershell 5+?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

**Background**

I've been working with PowerShell for a few months and come from a Java and VB Script background and may be suffering from preconceptions.  I am trying to create a sort of deployment script for a suite of scheduled tasks. Since they all run in PowerShell I'm using PowerShell to perform the operations.  I also had found an example of capturing a secure password so that I can set the "run as" credentials which is why I'm trying to plow through the errors I am encountering instead of trying to use the schdtasks CMD approach.  I have been searching high and low for an example or documented instance of the error I am seeing with no great success.

**Question**

In my script, I create a Trigger object, an Action object, a SettingsSet, and a ScheduledTask.  I'm using splatting to populate these objects arguments because it allows me to do some assignments conditionally.  This is all being  fed by a csv file which serves as a manifest that is easy for the administrator to maintain.  The goal is to allow them to update the csv, run my Register Tasks script, and know that all 40 or so tasks have been registered precisely without having to go through the Task Scheduler UI.

I am however running into an error:

> System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance". ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance".

Here is a condensed version of my code:

```
$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 5am -AsJob -Once

$settings = @{                       
        'Disable'                  = $true;
        'ExecutionTimeLimit'        = (New-TimeSpan -Days 1);
        'AsJob'                     = $true;
        'RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable' = $true;
        'Priority'                  = 10;
        'StartWhenAvailable'        = $true;
    }

if ($settings_allowstartondemand -eq $false) {
        $settings.add('DisallowDemandStart', $true)
}

$settingsSet = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet @settings 


$task = Register-ScheduledTask -Description $description -TaskName $taskName -TaskPath $taskFolderName -Settings $settingsSet -Trigger $taskTrigger -User $username -Password $password -Force $true
```

That last line is the one where my error is thrown.  Code and more explanation below but the basic question is why am I seeing this error and how do I resolve it?

**What I have tried**

Near as I can tell from printing the objects out to the console, the trigger and the settings set are both seen as type ThrottlingJob.  I am not sure why that is but my thought is that I need to convert it to a CimInstance to appease the Register-ScheduledTask cmdlet.

Here's the full stack trace.

> System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance". ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ThrottlingJob" to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance".
> at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ThrowInvalidCastException(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType)
> at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertNoConversion(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
> at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConversionData`1.Invoke(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
> at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTypeTable)
> at System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.Transform(EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics, Object inputData, Boolean bindingParameters, Boolean bindingScriptCmdlet)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.Transform(EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics, Object inputData, Boolean bindingParameters, Boolean bindingScriptCmdlet)
> at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata, ParameterBindingFlags flags) at 166

After the line that is throwing the error I attend to setting some additional trigger parameters and the action.  My code doesn't get this far yet so I don't know if this part will work or not.  It is based loosely on examples I've found elsewhere.

```
if ($trigger_interval -eq '-RepetitionInterval') {
        
        $task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = "PT" + $trigger_duration +"M"
        
     }
     elseif ($trigger_interval -eq "-Daily") {     
            
         $task.Triggers.Repetition.Duration = "P" + $trigger_duration + "D"
     }
     elseif ($trigger_interval -eq "-DaysOfWeek"){            
         $task.Triggers.DaysOfWeek = $trigger_duration
     }

     if($null -ne $taskAction -and $taskAction -ne ""){
       # $parms.add("Action",$taskAction)
       $task.Actions.add($taskAction)
    }


     $task | Set-ScheduledTask
```

All help and correction appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `-AsJob` parameters - they make the commands return asynchronous job objects instead of just executing synchronously. The last `$true` after `-Force` is also unnecessary and will likely cause another error to be thrown once the first issue is solved :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MathiasR.Jessen, I made both suggested changes but the result was the same.  For reference, I'm calling the script from my visual studio code terminal > powershell.exe -file registertasks.ps1, so hopefully I'm not falling into the 'powershell doesn't see your changes' trap, which would typically be indicated by an identical result after a change.

Comment: Did you remove both the `-AsJob` parameter switch from `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` AND the `'AsJob'` entry in `$settings`? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - ho! No I had not. That moved the ball down the court.  Thank you.  So, if I want these tasks to be registered to run as background jobs, what is the proper way if -AsJob causes this strange issue?

Comment: Scheduled tasks _are_ background jobs by default - you'd have to actively do something to make them run in the foreground - you've already got everything you need ;)

Comment: Thank you - I'm curious why the -AsJob parameter exists at all then, but my issue seems to be resolved.  I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: It exists on all CIM cmdlets so that you can easily turn long-running operations into _PowerShell background jobs_ (not the same as a scheduled task). In that case you would use it like: `$task = Some-Command -AsJob; Do-OtherStuff; While-WaitingForJob; $result = $task |Receive-Job`